# sql insert using select, case and subquery inside

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
select * into #transacTbl from tmpTrans
insert
   select
       (case when tmpT.TranStatus = 10
           then(
                select ID, 'Returned')
           else(
                select ID, 'GoodSale')
           end)
   from
   (
       select * from MainTransacSource
    ) as tmpT
```

I want to be able to insert the details of a transaction into a different table with a label if it is a returned or good sale/transaction. I did this to avoid the cursor so please avoid giving a solution using a cursor.

I know the code looks good but what I'm experiencing is that, the case statement only returns one value via subquery.

This is a simplified version of the code; I have at least 6 types of cases and should be able to insert by ROW. I hate to think that I have to repeat each case per column because the actual number of columns is about 38.

You may suggest another work-around if this doesn't fit the logic. Of course, without a cursor.

Comment: Put a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: If you have same logic repeated for different column, try using functions to achieve that.

Comment: Hey buddy. did the answer solve your issue? if so, it's good practice to tick it. This helps future visitors and is good for the answerer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without access to your tables and not knowing more about what precisely you want to acheive, try *something like* this:

```
select * into #transacTbl from tmpTrans
insert
   select tmpT.ID,
       (case when tmpT.TranStatus = 10
        then 'Returned'
        else 'GoodSale'
        end)
   from
      (select * from MainTransacSource) as tmpT <OR simply MainTransacSource tmpT (maybe)>
```

Cheers.